# Fast way to convert UTF8 to UCS-2 / UTF-16 to feed SSIS Bulk insert task

Tags: sql-server, powershell, unicode, utf-8, ssis

My current situation:

I am using **SSIS 2014** in order to load daily **379 files** (tab delimited files from AS400 in **UTF8**) that take up **20GB** .

My SSIS flow is this:
[image: ssis flow]

The first task is a script task:

```
string path= (string)Dts.Variables["dataPath"].Value;
string name = (string)Dts.Variables["fileName"].Value;
string from = Path.Combine(path, name) + ".tsv";
string to = Path.ChangeExtension(from, "txt");
Dts.Log("Starting "+to.ToUpper(),0,null);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(from, Encoding.UTF8, false, 1000000))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to,false, Encoding.Unicode, 1000000))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());    
    }
}
```

I need to make this flow faster. The only part that i have yet to optimize is the script convert to unicode..

I have tried to disable this task and specify in the Bulk insert task that the file is codepage 650001 , but i get an error that the server does not support this codepage. Obviously SSIS does not conver ton the fly utf8->unicode and then send it to SQL Server.

So i am stuck with the task to convert the files prior to bulk insert.

Now i am searching for the fastest way to do this. The current way is fast but i need to know how i can gain performance in this step with other techniques like:

-Powershell ?

-Command-line application (own built console app or any open-source?)

Thanks everyone

Comment: quick note: MSSQL 2016 will support it natively on Bulks  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411.aspx#UTF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried powershell option and at its best it matches the speed of my existing ssis setup. That is a sinlge task to load,convert,bulk insert into the database.

I also tried a console c# app but it didn't go faster than .

So i ended up with a modified SSIS task as follows:
[image]

I just splited the task into 4 tasks that each and everyone of them deals with separate set of text files.

Answer (score 1):

See if this isn't faster than your current method:

```
Get-Content $dataPath\$fileName.tsv -Encoding UTF8 -ReadCount 2000 |
 Add-Content -Encoding Unicode $dataPath\$fileName.txt
```

Comment: I have tried that but without readcount..I will test it and let you know

Comment: It is faster with the readcount but it just matches the ssis single task. I think i will just split my ssis task into 4 portions

Comment: Powershell converts everything to Unicode internally.  You could use -ReadCount and Foreach to read, ConvertFrom-CSV (using a tab delimiter) and then bulk insert, skipping the intermediate file altogether.